# Can objects use global variables declared outside of their class?

Tags: mql5

I would need that feature for a stop loss-object including a multiplier that increments every time (i.e. at every interval) it's called, but before its first call (i.e. upon opening a position) it must be reset to 0 (resetting it at the end of the SL-object instead is not possible because the object won't be called when the SL is hit). When I tried using a global variable declared outside of the SL-class I got a compilation error ("missing declaration"; the class is placed in an include file in case that info matters).

Is there another way than making my SL-object a function (which can access global variables) instead?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int  stoplossMultiplier,
     lastOpenedTicket;

void OnInit(){
     stoplossMultiplier = 0;
     lastOpenedTicket   = 0;                // also possible to find among open
}

int  TradeSend(){
  // do what you need here, include ticket = OrderSend(); function
  // compute lot based on stoplossMultiplier
     lastOpenedTicket = ticket;
}

void OnTick(){
     if ( lastOpenedTicket >  0 ){
          if ( !isTicketExist( lastOpenedTicket() ){
                if (  isClosedByStopLoss( lastOpenedTicket() ) ){
                      stoplossMultiplier = 0;
                }else{
                      stoplossMultiplier++;
                }
          }
     }
}

bool isTicketExist(      int ticket ){ /* make sure order is open        */ }
bool isClosedByStopLoss( int ticket ){ /* loop over OrdersHistoryTotal() */ }
```

Comment: Many thanks for the idea, I realized it by means of "[global class variable] currPosID = PositionGetInteger(POSITION_IDENTIFIER);" etc.

Comment: @user3666197 you don‘t need to tell me, I upvoted or accepted every single answer to my questions, sometimes even both. Maybe you missed that it was my own question and I had already accepted it. If everybody gave as many points as me we‘d all be point millionaires already! ;-)

Comment: @user3666197 PS: please feel free to upvote my question ;-)